# USB C Monitor on Dell Precision 3520 running Ubuntu 20.04 stops working after opening Evolution email client

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, multiple-monitors, evolution

I have a Dell Precision 3520 laptop running Ubuntu 20.04. I have been successfully using it with an external monitor using the HDMI output on the laptop. I recently purchased a second external monitor and have connected using the USB C port on the laptop with a USB C to HDMI cable. When the laptop boots up, I get the Ubuntu/Dell splash screen mirrored across all three monitors. With the Ubuntu sign on screen, the sign on screen is stretched across all three monitor with the login box appearing on the laptop screen. After signing in, all three monitors work with the desktop extended across all three screens.

However, when I open the Evolution email client, the screen connected via the USB C port loses the video signal and goes blank. It still appears the Screen Display in Settings.

I found an article that suggested deleting the .config/monitors.xml file and rebooting. This seems to sometimes, bit not always, gets the USB C monitor working again until I open Evolution again.

I am running 64-bit Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (5.4.0-65-generic), Gnome 3.36.8 and X11. The laptop has both Mesa Intel Integrated HD Graphics 630 (KBL GT2) and Nvidia GM107GLM Quadro M620 Mobile (using the proprietary nvidia-driver-460 driver). In the nvidia-settings application, the PRIME Profile is set to (NVIDIA Performance Mode) rather than NVIDIA On-Demand or Intel (Power Saving Mode), which I assumes means that I cam using Nvidia graphics all of the time.

I am using Evolution 3.36.4-0ubuntu1 (i.e not the latest stable version, which is 3.38).

This does seem like a bug as it is working and opening Evolution causes it to stop working. However, I am sure where the bug is and to whom it would be best to report it.

Below is my .config/monitors.xml file in its current state with the USB C monitor not working. I am not sure what other information will be required to diagnose this problem, so let me which logs / tools might provide more information and I will add them to this post.

```
<monitors version="2">
<configuration>
    <logicalmonitor>
      <x>1920</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <scale>1</scale>
      <monitor>
        <monitorspec>
          <connector>HDMI-1</connector>
          <vendor>HPN</vendor>
          <product>HP 27fw</product>
          <serial>3CM90508MJ   </serial>
        </monitorspec>
        <mode>
          <width>1920</width>
          <height>1080</height>
          <rate>60</rate>
        </mode>
      </monitor>
    </logicalmonitor>
    <logicalmonitor>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <scale>1</scale>
      <primary>yes</primary>
      <monitor>
        <monitorspec>
          <connector>eDP-1</connector>
          <vendor>BOE</vendor>
          <product>0x06f1</product>
          <serial>0x00000000</serial>
        </monitorspec>
        <mode>
          <width>1920</width>
          <height>1080</height>
          <rate>60.026748657226562</rate>
        </mode>
      </monitor>
    </logicalmonitor>
    <logicalmonitor>
      <x>3840</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <scale>1</scale>
      <monitor>
        <monitorspec>
          <connector>DP-1</connector>
          <vendor>DEL</vendor>
          <product>DELL S2719H</product>
          <serial>8937FM2</serial>
        </monitorspec>
        <mode>
          <width>1920</width>
          <height>1080</height>
          <rate>60</rate>
        </mode>
      </monitor>
    </logicalmonitor>
  </configuration>
  <configuration>
    <logicalmonitor>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <scale>1</scale>
      <primary>yes</primary>
      <monitor>
        <monitorspec>
          <connector>eDP-1-1</connector>
          <vendor>BOE</vendor>
          <product>0x06f1</product>
          <serial>0x00000000</serial>
        </monitorspec>
        <mode>
          <width>1920</width>
          <height>1080</height>
          <rate>60.026748657226562</rate>
        </mode>
      </monitor>
      <monitor>
        <monitorspec>
          <connector>DP-1-1</connector>
          <vendor>DEL</vendor>
          <product>DELL S2719H</product>
          <serial>8937FM2</serial>
        </monitorspec>
        <mode>
          <width>1920</width>
          <height>1080</height>
          <rate>60</rate>
        </mode>
      </monitor>
    </logicalmonitor>
  </configuration>
  <configuration>
    <logicalmonitor>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <scale>1</scale>
      <primary>yes</primary>
      <monitor>
        <monitorspec>
          <connector>DP-1</connector>
          <vendor>DEL</vendor>
          <product>DELL S2719H</product>
          <serial>8937FM2</serial>
        </monitorspec>
        <mode>
          <width>1920</width>
          <height>1080</height>
          <rate>60</rate>
        </mode>
      </monitor>
      <monitor>
        <monitorspec>
          <connector>eDP-1</connector>
          <vendor>BOE</vendor>
          <product>0x06f1</product>
          <serial>0x00000000</serial>
        </monitorspec>
        <mode>
          <width>1920</width>
          <height>1080</height>
          <rate>60.026748657226562</rate>
        </mode>
      </monitor>
    </logicalmonitor>
  </configuration>
</monitors>
```